# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: node.js

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : '***',
  password : '***',
  database : '***',
  port: '3000',
});

connection.query('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE id_vk = "'+id_vk+'"',function(err,rows){
var name3;
var image3;
var balance_real;
     if(err) throw err; //270 строка
       balance_real = (rows[0].balance);
});
```

/var/log/installer/eroors.js:270
     if(err) throw err;
             ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at Socket. (/var/log/installer/eroors.js:263:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at /var/log/installer/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)

Comment: Очевидно, на порту 3000 нету никакого mysql, вот и не может подключиться

Comment: Сервер: localhost:3306 это написано в бд, я поменял порт на 3006 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: Очевидно, на порту 3306 или 3006 тоже по каким-то причинам никого нет